# Connection refused between Spring and Mysql Docker Containers

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to run a docker network with Mysql and Spring containers. But when I run with "`docker-compose up`" I am getting *Connection Refused* error

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mediquiz
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1234
    ports:
      - "3307:3307"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql

  web:
    image: mediserver
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3307/mediquiz
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: 1234
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO: update

volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

and `application-properties.yml` file

```
spring:
  datasource:
    password: 1234
    url: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3307/mediquiz
    username: root
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    show-sql: true
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
```

I tried different options to connect - with localhost and with my ip, trying different configurations but it didn't work. The idea is that I can connect to the container database from the Intellij Idea Database tab, but I cannot connect from the Spring container

Comment: The default port for mysql is `3306`, not `3307`. Thus, we should replace all occurences of `3307` with `3306`.

Comment: Mysql port is default 3306. Why do you expose and specify 3307 everywhere?

Comment: Because I have a local mysql server on that port. So I run the docker one on 3307

Comment: But you do not tell that the mysql server. You just assume because you specify that port it automatically runs on that port. Thats not the case. Your mysql server inside your container still runs on port 3306.

Comment: Connections between containers don't use (or require) `ports:`; use the standard MySQL port 3306 in `$SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`, and as the second `ports:` number if you do need to access the database directly from outside of Docker.